# AWS SageMaker Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker

I know that for example, with Qubole's Hive offering which uses Zeppelin notebooks, that I can use Spark SQL to execute native SQL commands to interact with Hive tables.  I can read from external tables and create internal tables, or just run ad-hoc queries.

I am working on a project in AWS.  I have data in S3, with external tables created in Athena.  I have found articles, and followed them to setup some Jupyter notebooks, but I don't see how I can have notebooks running Spark SQL.  Is this possible?

If not, what is the best mechanism in the AWS ecosystem for encapsulating logic to create internal tables from external tables, for secondary data processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1) run Jupyter notebooks on EMR: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks.html

2) run Jupyter notebooks on SageMaker: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs.html

Both support PySpark, so you should be able to run SQL queries on whatever backend your data lives in.